# Can I re-use my app IPA, edit assets in it and update CodeResources with a script?

Tags: objective-c, code-signing, assets, ios

I've created an app that is reskinnable by just changing asset files. In theory, I could just unzip the IPA file, update my assets, then rezip it as a new version. Of course this doesn't work because of code signing and CodeResources hashes will not match my new assets. Is there anyway I can update CodeResources hashes without having to recompile my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use the `codesign` utility. `codesign` will let you replace any existing signature with one for the identity you specify. (Here's a good [blog post](http://furbo.org/2008/11/12/the-final-test/) on the subject.)

You can see exactly what parameters Xcode is passing to `codesign` by looking in your build logs. Find the line beginning with "CodeSign AppName...", select it, and then click on the little button that appears to the right. It'll show you the raw `codesign` command Xcode executed to sign your app. You should be able to unzip the .ipa, replace your assets, zip, and run the command from Xcode to re-sign the app.